# How to control a motor with two inputs using arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am using an arduino uno and I am trying to control a motor with two inputs which I found in a small car I used to have as a child.
I connected the first pin of the motor to the arduino ground and the second one to the VCC and the motor started turning.
However, when I write the following code the motor doesn't work.

```
void setup() {
pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
}
void loop() {
}
```

(I have connected the first pin of the motor to the ground and the second one to pin 8 of arduino).
Does anybody know why that happens?

Comment: So you have nothing connected to pin 8, right?

Comment: No I have connected digital pin 8 directly to the input of the motor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get a certain amount of current from an Arduino output pin. In general, you can light an LED with a direct connection to an output pin, but motors require more current. A detailed discussion is [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoPinCurrentLimitations).

To control a device such as a motor which needs more current than the output pin can provide directly, you can use an external transistor. You can buy circuits that implement this idea, such as this [Motor Shield for Arduino](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1438).

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Arduino is supposed to work with power consuming stuff (like mhopeng said, you may use LED in such a scheme, but not something more consuming): a motor should be between GND and 5V and if you want to control it, you have to use a transistor connected to an output pin.

I had [a similar question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22672/is-that-correct-that-input-and-output-pins-are-not-supposed-to-have-current-thro) once, it may be of help, too. Also, it may be a good idea to ask further questions at arduino.SE.